# SQL Query to Retrieve Non-Duplicate-Row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a table `documents`  (`id`, `user_id`, `unique_document_id`, `version`, `date`).

Example of entries are:

```
(1, 1, 1001, 1, null),
(1, 1, 1001, 2, null),
(1, 2, 1002, 1, null)
```

Currently I have a query which selects and displays the details:

```
select d.* from documents d
where d.user_id = 1 
order by d.date desc
limit 10
offset 0
```

But I want non duplicate rows using `unique_document_id` and `having max(version)`.

The output should be like: `(1, 1, 1001, 2, null)`, `(1, 2, 1002, 1, null)`

Can I achieve this by modifying the query or do I need to handle this at other place?
Something using `group by unique_document_id and max(version)`.

Comment: Yes, `group by` and `max(version)` would be the way to go indeed. You need to group by all fields that aren't aggregated.

Comment: First, figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you can use ROW_NUMBER() analytic function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select d.* from documents d
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Unique_document_id, MAX(version) version
from documents
GROUP BY Unique_document_id) b ON a.Unique_document_id= b.Unique_document_id  
AND a.version = b.version
```

Comment: Thanks that did work.

Comment: wha you negetive this answer

Comment: I had accidentally clicked it twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql-server and not postgresql then a window function will help:

```
With orderedVersions As (
    Select id, user_id, unique_document_id, Version, [date], RowNo = Row_Number() Over (Partition By Unique_Document_id Order By Version desc)
      From documents)
Select id, user_id, unique_document_id, Version, [date]
  From orderedVersions
  Where RowNo = 1;
```

So, yes you can achieve it by modifying the query.
If the table is very large, then you might also consider performance tuning by creating indexes, but this query should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (Works for MySql)

```
select a.* from doc_table a 
where (a.user_id, a.Unique_document_id, a.version) in
(select d.user_id, d.Unique_document_id, max(d.version)
from doc_table d group by d.user_id, d.Unique_document_id)
```